# How to setup logstash 1.4.2 email plugin without authentication in SMTP

Tags: email, logstash

I have setup logstash 1.4,2  running with elasticsearch in CentOS 6. I want a simple way to send emails when a typical errors occur in log, I am picking logs from different log files. In logstash docs online I found example for latest version only that is 2.0. and I dont want gmail example that doesn't work in my case.
one more thing do I need to enable email plugin or just directly add it into logstash conf file?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I had worked on logstash-1.4.2 earlier recently updated to 2.0,  and I had implemented email plugin. I will share one example conf file with email setup for local smtp.

```
        input { 
              file {
              type => 'file'
              path => '/home/tech/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/logs/em.log'
              start_position => beginning 
            }
        }

        filter {
              if [type] == "file" {
                 grok {
              # The grok filter will use the below pattern and on successful match use
                # any captured values as new fields in the event.
                 match => { 'message' => '([\w\.]*(ERROR|Exception))' }
                 }
                }
        }

        #here is the output will be displayed in Kibana and on ERROR it will send notification
        output {
              elasticsearch { host => localhost }
              if  "ERROR" in [message]  {
              email  {
                       options => [ "smtpIporHost", "YOUR-SMTP-IP",
                         "port", "25"
                       ]
                        from => "<myemail@example.com>"
                        subject => "Logstash alert on Error "
                        to => "recipeint@example.com"
                        via => "smtp"
                        body => "Here is the event line that occured: %{message}  %{@timestamp}  %{host}"
                        htmlbody => "<h2 align='center'>%{host}</h2><br/><h3>Details</h3><br/><div align='center' style='color:red'>%{message}</div><div align='center'>%{@timestamp}</div><div align='center'>%{@version}</div>"
               }
            }
           stdout { codec => rubydebug }
      }
```

First you need to check the email plugin is installed 
logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/outputs/email.rb
If it is not there you can install it by running this command.
        ./bin/plugin install contrib

If you have plugin setup and now you can test the script.
./bin/logstash -f my-logstash.conf

It will show you few warning and read the log files if error is there will send that in email.
whenever this file will change it will read.

Please let me know if you need any detail to test this sample.

Comment: Thanks for your help, really made my day. It is working absolutely fine :)